# How do I create a Word doc containing a chart without an IOException?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to programmatically create a Word doc from a template (dotx) file in C#. I'm using Microsoft's Open-XML-SDK Nuget library. This is a minimal example of what I'm doing:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        CreateDocument(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        memoryStream.CopyTo(File.Create("Output.docx"));
    }
    
    private static void CreateDocument(Stream outputStream)
    {
        using var document = WordprocessingDocument.CreateFromTemplate("Template.dotx");
        CreateChart(document.MainDocumentPart); // Commenting this line will make the code work
        document.Clone(outputStream);
    }
    
    private static void CreateChart(MainDocumentPart mainPart)
    {
        var chartPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<ChartPart>("rId110");
        var chartSpace = new ChartSpace();
        var chart = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Chart();
        chartSpace.Append(chart);
        chartPart.ChartSpace = chartSpace;
    }
```

Saving the output.docx works fine until I add a ChartPart. Doing that causes an exception:

> System.IO.IOException: Entries cannot be opened multiple times in Update mode.
> at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry.OpenInUpdateMode()
> at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry.Open()
> at System.IO.Packaging.ZipStreamManager.Open(ZipArchiveEntry zipArchiveEntry, FileMode streamFileMode, FileAccess streamFileAccess)
> at System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackagePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode streamFileMode, FileAccess streamFileAccess)
> at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
> at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream()
> at System.IO.Packaging.InternalRelationshipCollection.WriteRelationshipPart(PackagePart part)
> at System.IO.Packaging.InternalRelationshipCollection.Flush()
> at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.FlushRelationships()
> at System.IO.Packaging.Package.DoWriteRelationshipsXml(PackagePart p)
> at System.IO.Packaging.Package.DoOperationOnEachPart(PartOperation operation)
> at System.IO.Packaging.Package.Flush()
> at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.Save()
> at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.Clone(Stream stream, Boolean isEditable, OpenSettings openSettings)
> at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.Clone(Stream stream)
> at ChartInWordDocDemo.Program.CreateDocument(Stream outputStream) in Program.cs:line 20
> at ChartInWordDocDemo.Program.Main() in Program.cs:line 11

This code is available here: https://github.com/simon-chester/ChartInWordDocDemo

Any ideas on how to fix this please?

Comment: Microsoft word normal format is Not OpenXML.  Do you have a docx file or a xml file?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really get this working. I just worked-around it. I created a chart in the template, and then just wrote code that manipulates that existing chart instead.